# Drawing a Direction using the Google Maps JavaScript API from npm

Tags: javascript, google-maps, npm, google-maps-api-3

First Javascript code for a couple of years, I try to load the Google Maps Javascript API ***npm*** package to try to load a map and draw a direction between 2 points (Lille and Biarritz, passing by Paris and Bordeaux). I ended with an error from the Google API which code is UNKNOWN_ERROR and the message is

> A directions request could not be processed due to a server error. The
> request may succeed if you try again.

Unfortunately, I've tried several times in the last 48h without success.

***config.js***

```
export const API_KEY = 'XXXXXX___A_VALID_GOOGLE_API_KEY_HERE_XXXXXXX'
// the key has access to Directions API & Maps JavaScript API
```

***index.js***

```
import { API_KEY } from './config.js';
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

//////////////////////
// Direction API Test
//////////////////////


const calculateAndDisplayRoute = async function (
  directionsService,
  directionsRenderer
) {
  try {
    const google = window.google; // Fix for ESLint Err google is not defined
    const res = await directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        query: 'Lille',
      },
      destination: {
        query: 'Biarritz',
      },
      waypoints: [
        { location: 'Paris, France' },
        { location: 'Bordeaux, France' },
      ],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidTolls: true,
      avoidHighways: false,
      drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: new Date(Date.now()),
        trafficModel: 'pessimistic',
      },
    });
    console.log(res);
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Directions request failed 
        Code: ${e.code} 
        Message: ${e.message} `);
  }
};

////////////
// API Load
////////////

const init = async function () {
  try {
    const loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      version: 'weekly',
    });

    const res = await loader.load();
    if (!res) return;

    const google = window.google; // Fix for ESLint Err google is not defined
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: { lat: 47, lng: 2 },
    });

    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    document
      .getElementById('go')
      .addEventListener(
        'click',
        calculateAndDisplayRoute.bind(
          this,
          directionsService,
          directionsRenderer
        )
      );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

init();
```

But, I've got this weird error and I've got no idea how to fix it :/

```
Directions request failed 

Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR 
Message: DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: UNKNOWN_ERROR:
A directions request could not be processed due to a server error.
The request may succeed if you try again.
```

Comment: The directions service code works for me [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/eunxsack/) (admittedly I didn't build it using npm...)

Comment: And the API Key is working properly. Probably something is going wrong with Parcel on something else...I'll keep you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the problem was on the bundler side which was Parcel. I've built a SvelteKit version of this code and it works like a charm. As SwelteKit uses Rollup as a bundler (and Vite), I guess it's just the way to go at the time of writing.